# Marker detection Methods in Augmented Reality

Tags: augmented-reality, marker

I have placed markers in room and have a moving camera. I want to detect location of room, the camera is looking using markers detection technique. Can any one tell me methods for marker detection??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am searching for the same so somebody else could be easily more helpful.
I just saw this two links:

http://studierstube.icg.tugraz.at/thesis/marker_detection.pdf

http://infi.nl/blog/view/id/56/